# MongoDB replicate a sharded setup

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I want to get sharding up together with replication. Don't get me wrong, I managed to install a sharded cluster that accesses replication sets as shards.

My problem is to get the sharded cluster processes replicated just like this:

```
[ Replication Set 1 ]  <--> [ Replication Set 2 ] <--> [ Replication Set 3 ]
         |                           |                          |
         v                           v                          v
[ Sharded Cluster 1 ]       [ Sharded Cluster 2 ]      [ Sharded Cluster 3 ]
  |                           |                          |             
  |--> [ Shard 1 ]            |--> [ Shard 1 ]           |--> [ Shard 1 ]
  |--> [ Shard 2 ]            |--> [ Shard 2 ]           |--> [ Shard 2 ]
  |--> [ Shard 3 ]            |--> [ Shard 3 ]           |--> [ Shard 3 ]
```

I'd prefere this setup above replicating cluster shards due to the single point of failure. When sharded cluster (e.g. the `mongos` process) dies, then I still got 2 processes up and running.

Is this kind of setup possible in any way?

Comment: Its reverse. Shards are primary partitions of database, then there are replications of these partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't work. Sharding and replicating always works the other way around:

```
[      Sharded Cluster                     ]

[ Shard 1    ] [ Shard 2    ] [ Shard 3    ]
  |              |              |
  |->SetMember   |->SetMember   |->SetMember  
  |->SetMember   |->SetMember   |->SetMember 
  |->SetMember   |->SetMember   |->SetMember
```

When you worry about the mongos process being a bottleneck and single point of failure, note that [you can have multiple mongos servers accessing the same cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/#sharding-in-mongodb).

Comment: Wow thanks, that is what I did not know about and it is exactly what I needed!